# Vue filters migration from vue 1 to vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

I have problem with migratiing filters from vue 1 to vue 2, I created exactly what I need here (highlighting text which match the input text):

```
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
     searchParams: [
     { key: '' }
     ],
      suggestions: [
        { message: 'Foo' },
        { message: 'Bar' },
        { message: 'Foobar' },
        { message: 'pikachu' },
        { message: 'raichu' }
      ]
    }
  },
  filters: {
    highlight: function(words, query){
        var iQuery = new RegExp(query, "ig");
        return words.replace(iQuery, function(matchedTxt,a,b){
            return ('<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matchedTxt + '</span>');
        });
    }
  }
})


// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo'
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5ac1quc/23/ VUE-1 resource
https://jsfiddle.net/t5ac1quc/25/ VUE-2 resource

I would be very grateful, for all the answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ac1quc/27/).

```html
<template id="grid-template">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="suggest in suggestions" v-html="highlight(suggest.message, filterKey)"></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<div id="demo">
  <form>
    Search <input v-model="searchParams.key">
  </form>
  <demo-grid :filter-key="searchParams.key"></demo-grid>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      suggestions: [
        { message: 'Foo' },
        { message: 'Bar' },
        { message: 'Foobar' },
        { message: 'pikachu' },
        { message: 'raichu' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    highlight: function(words, query) {
      var iQuery = new RegExp(query, "ig");
      return words.replace(iQuery, function(matchedTxt,a,b){
          return ('<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matchedTxt + '</span>');
      });
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchParams: {
      key: '',
    },
  },
});
```

Summary:

- When using `<script>` tags to store templates, set `type="template"` (or similar) to prevent the browser from executing the template as JavaScript. Or better yet use `<template>` instead.
- `{{{ html }}}` syntax is no longer supported. In Vue 2 you must use the `v-html` directive instead.
- Since `v-html` is a directive (and doesn't use `{{ }}` interpolation), it doesn't use the filter syntax. Use a method instead.
- You had some issues with the scope of the data. The root component needs to define data for `searchParams` which is used in its template. Also `searchParams` was an array but you weren't using it as an array (`searchParams.key`); this will not work with Vue 2 (all reactive data properties must be properly declared upfront).

Comment: hello, one more thing, could you see what doen't work with this fiddle?
I would like  to highlight only the first letters of the strong. Like Foofoo, and highlight only 'Foo' here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5ac1quc/30/

Comment: You mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ac1quc/31/)? Do you only want to highlight the first occurrence, or highlight only from the beginning of the string?